# EF Code first :Remove Extra foreign keys from a central many to many relationships table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have a central table to handle translations, many entities could have a collection of translations. I'm using EF 6.0 code first. 
For each entity EF generate a foreign key in Translation table, to avoid this, I decide to add 3 columns :TableName, ColumnName and EntityKey to point to the given table.

```
public class CurrencyModel
{
  // more staff here 
  public ICollection<TranslationModel> Translations {get; set; }
}
public class CityModel
{
  // more staff here 
  public ICollection<TranslationModel> Translations {get; set; }
}

public class CountryModel
{
  // more staff here 
  public ICollection<TranslationModel> Translations {get; set; }
}

public class CategoryModel
{
  // more staff here 
  public ICollection<TranslationModel> Translations {get; set; }
}
```

How can I force EF to do not generate a foreign key for each table ?
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: This question has been asked many times in many variations. What you're looking for is *polymorphic associations*.

Comment: Gert Arnold, could you please tell me how it could be done using code ?

Answer (score 0):

After you create and add migration and before updating database you should use fluent api, Go to your DbContext class and check OnModelCreating method, In this method you can see .HasForeignKey(e => e....) on some of your entities ..
OnModelCreating method is where you can override EF conventions and force it to for example not generate a foreign key for each table ..

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I think if you have navigation properties in your classes then you can use them to navigate in c# code so you can for any reason go to OnModelCreating method and force ef to ignore creation of foreignKey, Although I think this is stupid work to do, But in answer to  "How can I force EF" I think this is where you can force EF and change it's conventions ..

Comment: The question is not how to tell EF *not* to create foreign keys. It's how to tell it not to do that *for each table*. OP wants `TranslationModel` to have only one FK referring to 4 tables, which of course is impossible (well, technically it's possible, but practically it isn't).

Comment: The best thing to do is to delete you answer.